# Edges when exporting a graphic

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

I use a graphics primitive:

```
  square = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 10]
```

And export it:

```
Export["square.pdf", square]
```

The resulting graphic in the pdf consists of both a rectangle and an edge (see image), which can be seperated in a vector-graphics software:

[image]

This leads to strange effects. Circles and Squares with the same Diameter/Edgelength are not equally big anymore. This also produces problems with Edges, as can be seen in the following example:

```
square = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, 
      ImageSize -> 10]
```

[image]

So how can I stop mathematica from producing the Edge?

Comment: On what operating system and what Mathematica version do you observe these problems?

Comment: I use Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10

Comment: I guess WL forgets to remove the default edge. I think this is a bug, as the issue has been fixed in some 13.2's beta testing versions.

Comment: Any ideas for a workaround? A circle does not have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to have been fixed in upcoming 13.2. Meanwhile, for versions *with* the issue, replacing `Rectangle` with `FilledCurve` seems to be a sufficient workaround.

```
$Version
(*Out[]= 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)*)

orig = Graphics[{
   {EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.1]}], Orange, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}
   , {EdgeForm[{Blue, Thickness[.2]}], Cyan, Rectangle[{-1, -1} + .5, {1, 1} + .6]}
   , {EdgeForm[], Gray, Rectangle[{-1, -1} - .6, {1, 1} - .3]}
   }, ImageSize -> 10]

fixed = orig /. Rectangle[{xm_, ym_}, {xM_, yM_}] :> 
  FilledCurve[Line@{{xm, ym}, {xM, ym}, {xM, yM}, {xm, yM}}]
```

Exporting `orig` directly does exhibit the extra edge (as extra `JoinedCurve`) issue:

```
orig // RightComposition[
  ExportString[#, "PDF"] &
  , ImportString[#, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}] &
  , Cases[#, FilledCurve | JoinedCurve, \[Infinity], Heads -> True] &
  , Tally
  ]
(*Out[]= {{FilledCurve, 3}, {JoinedCurve, 5}}*)
```

Exporting `fixed` seems to work:

```
fixed // RightComposition[
  ExportString[#, "PDF"] &
  , ImportString[#, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}] &
  , Cases[#, FilledCurve | JoinedCurve, \[Infinity], Heads -> True] &
  , Tally
  ]
(*Out[]= {{FilledCurve, 3}, {JoinedCurve, 1}}*)
```

Double check in Inkscape:

```
Export["rect_to_FilledCurve.pdf", fixed, "PDF"]
```

[image: Double checking in Inkscape]

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Mathematica 13.1, Windows 10) it helps to specify the PlotRangeClipping and the PlotRangePadding:

```
square = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Rectangle[{-1, 
-1}, {1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 50, PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding 
-> None]
```

Comment: If I open the exported pdf with a vector graphics program, the issue is the same. But thank you for the effort!